# Moving hive data from one Hadoop cluster to another without using distcp command?

Tags: hadoop

How to move hive data from one Hadoop cluster to another Hadoop cluster without using `distcp` command. As we can not use this. Do we have another option like Sqoop or Flume?

Answer (score 0):

**distcp** is the efficient way to move huge amounts of data from one hadoop cluster to another.

Sqoop and Flume cannot be used to transfer data from one hadoop cluster to another. Sqoop is predominantly used to move data between hadoop and relational databases whereas Flume is used to ingest streaming data to Hadoop.

Your other option would be to use:

1. high-throughput msg queue like Kafka, but this would become more complicated than using distcp.
2. Use traditional `hadoop fs` shell commands like `cp` or `get` followed by `put`

FYI when you are talking about Hive data, you also should consider keeping hive metadata (metastore) in-sync between the clusters.

Comment: Thanks for reply & suggestion Ashrith,

I was thinking that i can do like this:

sqoop import --connect jdbc:hive2://am1dlccmrhdn04.r1-core.r1.aig.net:10000/test_vk --driver org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver --username codspug --table sqooptest -m 1 --hive-import --target-dir /tmp/TESTVK/

From starting onward it is giving error like method not supported.

can we do it with Map Reduce program.or any other way to achieve this?

Pls help as u suggest we can use Kafka but here can't use kafka.

Pls help me on this?